# PHP better syntax check during edit

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I am working on a not so little project in PHP using Eclipe PDT.

I find myself wasting a lot of time because typing errors do neither lead to errors or warnings during edit. This means I get runtime errors (easy) or not (difficult to debug).

I like to give some examples:

Error in function call

```
$ret = $this->getListOfUniqueNames();
```

Typing a call like this hardly results in any error, because the content assists helps here.

The story changes if you use classes with interfaces, where content assist is not always available.

Example 1: () missing

```
$s = $this->mDataClass->getSchedule;
```

In this call I forgot (). PHP does not raise an edit error or an undefined constant, so this error comes up during runtime.

Example 2: undefined function

```
$s = $this->mDataClass->getSchedule();
```

This is a call to an undefined function. It should have been getScheduleList().

Example 3: undefined variable

```
$this-mVarTypingError = "abc";
```

This actually creates a new variable in the extended subclass. Can be prevented with __set in top class, but I do not think it is good practice to produce code to prevent typing errors.

I could not figure out if

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
```

would be benefitial.

So my question is: What can I do to prevent these type of typing mistakes that are caught in Java during compilation? I rather define all my vars then search for errors because I did not.

Comment: Ugh... I know this not a direct answer to your question, but... Try PHPStorm. It's a paid product, but the quality of this IDE just blew my mind when I first met it. Today we all use it in our company and it's really worth the money. (I'm not affiliated with JetBrains, just a user of PHPStorm)

Comment: 1) Learn to unit test your code 2) Use strict typing 3) change your IDE or at least install any plugin that does static code analysis as you type

Comment: I use NetBeans. Its free and has lots of features.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE. Personally, I am a fan of PHPStorm (though I have no affiliation with the company that created it). It will catch 100% of these issues on the fly and much, much more.

Comment: Eclipse is not an IDE?

Comment: It is, but I did not enjoy using it at all for PHP. Some people love it. Personally, I think PHPStorm is infinitely better. YMMV.

Comment: To clarify, Eclipse is not a true PHP IDE. It is often *used* as one, but PHP is not at all its forte. An IDE that doesn’t alert you to obvious errors on the fly is not really doing much for you that you couldn’t get out of a decent text editor.